# How to make it two seconds for Time.time?

Tags: unity, color, unityscript

```
var targetscript : Diamond;
var red : Color;
var orange : Color;

function Start () {
    gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = red;
}

function Update () {
    if (targetscript.score > 4) {
        gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(red, orange, Time.time);
    }
}
```

So right now, if the score is larger than 4 then it would change the camera background color to orange with lerp. But its too quick. I read on the internet that Time.time is 1 second. What is the alternative way but for 2 or 3 seconds? I tried this : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/328891/controlling-duration-of-colorlerp-in-seconds.html
I tried the code for the voted answer but it didn't work. It still lerps through quickly. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You seem to misunderstand `Lerp`. The last parameter is the blend-factor (not time) and should be  a value from `0 - 1`. In your case, a blend-factor of `0` results in red and `1` results in orange.

You can just plug in `Time.time`, but this value will get truncated to `1` as soon as it's bigger than `1`... and that point will be reached 1 second into your game. Doesn't sound like the thing you want to do.

So what you should do is have a "start-time" and a desired duration. Example:

```
var duration:float = 3; // duration of 3 seconds
var startTime:float = -1;
```

Then you need to assign the `startTime` as soon as your color-change starts and use it to calculate the time that has passed.
Example:

```
function Update () {
    if (targetscript.score > 4) {
        if(startTime < 0){
            startTime = Time.time;
        }
        gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = 
            Color.Lerp(red, orange, (Time.time - startTime) / duration);
    }
}
```

Comment: @mark You may also want to take a look at `Time.deltaTime`[ [Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) ] which returns the time since the last frame. I find that is usually more intuitive for me.